# VB Script to select options in a preexisting macro

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

First time here, so my apologies if this is answered and I failed to find it.

I have a script that is partially written, that opens an excel file, and within it, opens a preexisting macro.  I need to figure out how to make two selections on that macro, hit OK, and then rinse and repeat for other options.

I.E., open the macro, run option 1 from the top field, and option 1 from the lower field, OK, then run option 1 from the top field,  option 2 from the lower field, etc, ad nauseum.

The code I have so far to open is as follows:

```
Dim arts, objExcel

Set args = WScript.ARguments
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.visible = True

objExcel.Run "SetupSelections"
```

and I have a separate batch file that will make sure the script runs on the appropriate file.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code for `SetupSelections` and what is the issue that you're having with it?  The VBScript in your question is just the calling code...

Comment: This looks more like `vb-script` than `vba`. If so, please edit your question and apply more appropriate tags. You might also wish to view the description of the `macros` tag.

Comment: I will try to change the tag.  I do not have all the code for SetupSelections, which is part of my problem.

Comment: So this macro launches a userform and you are trying to manipulate the userform from VBScript? Sounds like you need some sort of `SendKeys` solution, though such solutions tend to be unreliable.

Comment: Yes. That is, I believe, what I am trying to do.

Comment: Figure out what heys you need to send and then send them, with little delays to help insure that the form is ready for the keys. Such solutions tend to be fragile since you have little ability to control if the right keystrokes are sent to the right window at the right time. Such code tends to randomly fail. If you are doing this for a client and the client has the code for `SetupSelections` perhaps you could tell them that you need the code if you are to do a good job.

Comment: So if I wanted it to do space bar, for example, then tab, I'd do: SendKeys" " followed by Sendkeys "{TAB}"?

Comment: Something like that. See this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx To get it to work you sometimes have to `Sleep` for a fraction of a second between some of the keys.

Comment: Got, thank you so much!